# So many DE options on login screen

Tags: desktop-environments

I have a lot of DE options on the login screen on my Ubuntu Budgie. Is that normal? May this cause a problem or slow my system? Below is a photo I took:

[image]

Comment: I have never seen two GNOME on Xorg entries. What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: If a user adds/install different DEs it might cause problems/interference.  DEs added by OS developers should not, they are tested to work well on system.  You only use one at a time, so the others are not used/turned off.

Comment: I have not installed any -extra- environments delibarately. I think that they might have come with some software i installed?

Comment: As far as I know, a user must install a DE as a DE.  Other software installs will not do it.  Linux OSs do usually come with a couple of choices(some have more) for DE.  Common choice would be DE on XORG or Wayland for Ubuntu types of OS.

Comment: Certain packages have dependencies that can cause parts, most or all of a desktop in (esp. tweak like tools), however Budgie is a different shell on the base GNOME system, thus most of GNOME's base is necessary (it's only the shell or top GUI (GNOME Shell) that is replaced by the Budgie shell)

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the information. So if i login to Gnome for example; is this as functional as the default ubuntu installation?

Comment: I can't be specific with GNOME as it's not my desktop of choice. I'll use a Lubuntu install by example; modern Lubuntu uses LXQt, and users have a Lubuntu or LXQt session they can login to. The Lubuntu choice provides all our configs & everything matches our manual; the LXQt session has many of our configs disabled for a nearer pure upstream LXQt experience, only parts will match our manual (& many things Ubuntu users expect won't be there). I assume it's similar with the GNOME & Ubuntu choices; Lubuntu/LXQt is Xorg only so we don't have Xorg/Wayland complication.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes, this is normal
2. no, this does not impact on speed.

These are merely different desktop methods. The idea is for you to pick the one you like most and use that.

If you want to see what takes performance log in and type `top` on command line. It will list all processes with the one using the most at the "top".

Me using Budgie:

```
top - 15:06:14 up  6:05,  1 user,  load average: 0,51, 0,46, 0,42
Tasks: 376 total,   1 running, 375 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2,7 us,  1,6 sy,  0,0 ni, 93,3 id,  2,4 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  15815,5 total,   8713,1 free,   2401,1 used,   4701,3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048,0 total,   2048,0 free,      0,0 used.  12507,3 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
  34256 rinzwind  20   0  988292  74872  45692 S  16,6   0,5   0:32.74 transmi+ 
   1023 root      20   0  661740 118256  74548 S   7,6   0,7  15:02.35 Xorg     
   1392 rinzwind  20   0 1117264 130644  76704 S   7,3   0,8   5:46.60 budgie-+ 
  15191 rinzwind  20   0  511868  72552  57348 S   6,6   0,4   0:02.44 tilix    
  14357 rinzwind  20   0 9063296 275888 165316 S   3,0   1,7   0:25.00 chrome   
    502 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   2,3   0,0   0:06.85 irq/146+ 
    503 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   1,3   0,0   0:02.82 irq/147+ 
    500 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   1,0   0,0   0:06.34 irq/144+
```

with Transmission, Tilix and chrome as programs active that I am using.

Comment: Thanks. I looked it up with "top" command and everything looks fine.